# While adding a new user in Microsoft Office 365 stuck at a results step

Tags: windows-7, user, office365

Recently I have signed up for Microsoft Office 365 and while trying all different features of this product, I wanted to share some documents with my friend so I decided to add a new user.

I have followed Microsoft's own guide on how to add a new user from this [guide](http://www.Microsoft.com/online/help/en-us/guides/adminsmb.htm). I can get all the way to Results and that's where I get stuck. All I can see is Results and please wait message with an animated circle for a long time and nothing is happening. Does any one know what is the problem and how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How many licenses did you pay for? it sounds like you simply bought one, and can't add more unless you buy more.

From your link "After you have added users to your service and assigned them a suite license, each user has the following items:", and later "On the Licenses page, select the licenses that you want to assign to the user."

I have set up MS Office 365, and its predecessor BPOS, and you have to have one license per user.

Comment: On the trial version I have 10 licenses and I already have used 1 for myself and when I try to create a new user it tells me that I have 9 licenses left.

Comment: Ahh, OK. Since it is done on the web, I would try it from another computer next to see if it can be isolated to your one computer. You are using IE, and not another browser? It should work with all of them, but I don't trust doing Microsoft operations like that without IE.

Comment: By the way, sometimes it is just their servers. I have had things like logins just stop working, and then start again later.

Comment: I will try again after 24hrs pass and see what happens

Comment: I have tried again but no luck so I have tried IE8 on a different PC and that worked. What I am also noticing is that Office 365 is not playing nice in IE9.

Comment: Turns out that I can actually use IE9 to create a new user account since I have done that on a different PC. Geez....

Comment: Try going to Tools>internet Options>Advanced, and Reset the browser.